# Can't show an outlet in Remix v2 Route File Naming conventions

Tags: reactjs, routes, remix.run, outlet

So I have this tree

```
routes/project.jsx
routes/project.$projectId.jsx
routes/project.$projectId.register.jsx
```

then

`project.jsx`

```
import { Outlet } from "@remix-run/react";

export default function Project() {
  return (
    <>
      <div>project</div>
      <Outlet />
    </>
  );
}
```

`projectId.jsx`

```
import { Outlet } from "@remix-run/react";

export default function Project() {
  return (
    <>
      <div>projectId</div>
      <Outlet />
    </>
  );
}
```

`register.jsx`

```
export default function Register() {
  return (
    <div>register</div>
  );
}
```

if I go to `http://localhost:3000/project/any-id-would-suit/register`

I expect to see on my html page

```
project
projectId
register
```

but I only see

```
register
```

did I make a mistake ? sure. which one ?

[EDIT]

`remix.config.js`

```js
module.exports = {
  future: {
    v2_meta: true,
    v2_routeConvention: true,
  },
  devServerPort: 8002,
};
```

Comment: Are you sure your app is configured to use the v2 routes? It looks like you're just seeing the behaviour as documented here https://remix.run/docs/en/v1/guides/routing#nested-urls-without-nesting-layouts

Comment: you're right it looks like this kind of behavior... although I think my config file is good - I'll put it in the original post so that it's properly formatted

Comment: I just tried on my local and it worked fine with the above routes + code. Are you sure your version of Remix supports v2 routes? I'm on 1.11.1

Comment: oh my god ! I started my project like 10 days ago, I didn't expect a new minor to come in between. I should have checked... thanks @RichardScarrott!

Answer (score 1):

I was in `1.10.1`.
Juste upgrade to the minimum compatible version `1.11.1` and it's working.